# Trying to send Form data through ajax to a sample PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Ajax to upload form data to my server where I validate it using PHP, the problem is that my Ajax request doesn't work.

I've used this snippet a few times previously, but this time it doesn't work.

I've checked, there's nothing in my console/network-tab in my browser.

> HTML

```
<form id="Create" style="display: none;" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Room name" required autofocus >  
  <select name="Category">
    <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
    <option value="Disscussion">Discussion</option>
    <option value="Family">Family</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

> JS (Ajax code)

```
$('#Create').on('submit' , function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();  
    $.ajax({
        url : "./process_php/Chat1.php" ,
        data : $('#Create').serialize() ,
        cache : false ,
        processData : false  ,
        //contentType : false ,
        type : "POST" ,

        success : function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        } 

    });

    return false ;

});
```

And my PHP page doesn't have anything except a single line which echo out the word 'Hello'

I've done a bit of research, but to no avail.

I've double checked my directories, they are alright.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There's no element with the ID of `Create` in your code. Have you defined your form opening tag?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just a typing mistake!

Comment: I've edited my question !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use an HTML `form`? And then in your PHP file, you handle the variables from there?

```
<form action="PHP file goes here" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Room name" required autofocus >
<select name="Category">
    <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
    <option value="Disscussion">Discussion</option>
    <option value="Family">Family</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Category = $_POST["Category"];
echo "Hello " . $Name . ". The Category you chose was " . $Category . ".";
?>
```

This should definitely get the job done. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I can use this but the problem is that I'm implementing chat feature, in Which one person creates a room and the rest joins, so I want everything to happen without the page getting refreshed.

Comment: @AragAggrawal Oh, in that case I recommend WebRTC

Comment: WebRTC is a great idea but I just wanted to know if there's a drawback in using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem before.

1. First, check all dependency are correct or not.
2. Then check whether function receive call on submit.
3. If above 2 are working then just do following change 
   replace `data : $('#Create').serialize()` 
   with `data : $('#Create').serializeArray()`

Hope this work for you
Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Create').on('submit' , function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();  
           $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "./process_php/Chat1.php",
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           data: new FormData(this),    
           cache: false, 
           success: function(response){ 
           console.log(response);

        }
      });

        return false ;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please verify if the control reaches to js file. For better debugging you can paste ur js code inline and try.Looks like `$('#Create').on('submit' , function(e) {` is not invoked.

Comment: The HTML uses the js file, I've verified this!